# How to check if an array contains a certain value?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am working with an array in this form:

```
"car_documents_attributes"=>{
    "1562523330183"=>{
        "id"=>"", "filename"=>"tyYYqHeqSFOnqLHEz5lO_rc_tispor12756_6wldwu.pdf", "document_type"=>"contract"
    }, 
    "1562523353208"=>{
        "id"=>"", "filename"=>"a9P8TyECRiKbI2YdRVZy_rc_tispor12756_bbtzdz.pdf", "document_type"=>"request"
    },
     "1562523353496"=>{
        "id"=>"", "filename"=>"WCM5FHOfSw6yNSUrfPPm_rc_tispor12756_dqu9r2.pdf", "document_type"=>"notes"
    },
    ...
}
```

I need to find out if in this array is an item where `document_type`=`contract` (there can be none, one or multiple ones).

The way I do it is looping through the array item by item, which can be slow if there are tens of items.

Is there a better and faster way to simply check if in the array is an item with `document_type` = `contract`?

Comment: There is no array in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a hash containing more hashes. What you can do is to access to `car_documents_attributes`, iterate over those hash values and check if any `document_type` is "contract":

```
data = {
  "car_documents_attributes" => {
    "1562523330183" => { "id" => "", "filename" => "tyYYqHeqSFOnqLHEz5lO_rc_tispor12756_6wldwu.pdf", "document_type" => "contract"},
    "1562523353208" => { "id" => "", "filename" => "a9P8TyECRiKbI2YdRVZy_rc_tispor12756_bbtzdz.pdf", "document_type" => "request" },
    "1562523353496" => { "id" => "", "filename" => "WCM5FHOfSw6yNSUrfPPm_rc_tispor12756_dqu9r2.pdf", "document_type" => "notes" }
  }
}
p data['car_documents_attributes'].any? { |_, doc| doc['document_type'] == 'contract' }
# true
```

---

Didn't know it was data coming from the params. If so, you do need to permit what's being received or convert the params to an unsafe hash.

Also, you can try using `fetch` instead `[]` when trying to get `car_documents_attributes`, because if that key isn't in `data`, it'll throw `nil`, which would throw a NoMethodError:

```
data.fetch('car_documents_attributes', []).any? { |_, doc| doc['document_type'] == 'contract' }
```

Comment: thank you. However, I needed to add `to_unsafe_h`, because the code was throwing error `rails undefined method `any?' for #<ActionController::Parameters:`. -> `data['car_documents_attributes'].to_unsafe_h.any? {...`

Comment: Yes, `ActionController::Parameters` is a different implementation which needs to be converted to an "unsafe" hash in order to invoke some methods. See the edit.